# getElementsByClassName seems not to be working

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to append a date to four inputs with same class but it's not working.

DOM:

```
<input class="time" value="" type="hidden">
```

Not working:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML = new Date();
document.getElementsByClassName("time").innerHTML = new Date();
```

Comment: Since these are `input` elements you need to use `.value`, not `.innerHTML`

Comment: @LGSon: ah slip my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of the input instead of its innerHTML:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].value = new Date();
```

```html
<input class="time" value="">
```